# Access application controller from didinsertelement view

Tags: ember.js

I want to access application controller so I can get/set a variable (selected_date) value.

```
myApp.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    selected_date: null,
  actions: {
    }
  }
});
```

I would like to make edits to selected_date from a view (didinsertelement), the controller for the view is:

```
myApp.CreportController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ["application"]
});
```

view:

```
CreportController View = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        var controller = this.get('controller');
        var selected_date = controller.get('controllers.application').get('selected_date');
        ...
```

Comment: `needs` has to be an array. Change it to `needs: ["application"]`. What kind of edits are you trying to make to selected_date? It doesn't look like you need `didInsertElement`.

Comment: I need to change the value of selected_date (type string) from the didinsert element

Comment: just edited the post code

Comment: My idea is access selected_date, get / set values from 3 different view, share this variable with 3 different views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the code with the solution:

```
var controller = this.get('controller');
var selected_date = controller.get('controllers.application').get('selected_date');
```

Answer (score 2):

You have your properties wrong. Using the `needs` functionality puts those controllers in a `controllers` property. Your view can then access its own controller using the `controller` property. So you need to do this in your view:

```
didInsertElement: function() {
    var selected_date = this.get('controller.controllers.application').get('selected_date');
}
```

Comment: I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Debug your code and figure out what is coming back as `undefined`. It's possible your view doesn't have a reference to its controller.

Comment: At second glance, you posted an unrelated controller and view (they're named differently). Are you trying to get the view's own controller or a different one?